# Python: как прочитать несколько листов Excel в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в Excel преобразовать «Sheet1» и «Sheet2» в список? В настоящее время я использую xlrd, как показано в приведенном ниже коде.
Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Мой код

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import xlrd
import sys

loc = 'excel.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc, encoding_override="iso-8859-5, cyrillic")
wb_name = wb.sheet_names()
count = len(wb_name)
data = []
column_excel =('Name', 'Course', 'Cost', 'level')
count_column = len(column_excel)
for i in range(count):
    ow = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xlsx').sheet_by_index(i)
    for x in range (0, 100):
        for i in range(count_column):
            try:
                if ow.cell_value(0, x) == column_excel[i]:
                    ips = ow.col_values(x, 1)
                    data.append(ips)
                    break
            except IndexError:
                continue
print(data)
```

Мой результат:

```
[['Andre'], [1], [200], [5],
['Sam'], [2], [100], [8],
[7], ['Antony'], [4], [150],
[9], ['Ben'], [3], [500]]
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[['Andre'], [1], [200], [5],
['Sam'], [2], [100], [8],
['Antony'], [4], [7], [150],
['Ben'], [3], [9], [500]]
```

Comment: "Мои результаты" не отличаются от ожидаемого результата. Что нужно-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик чтоб список отображал в таком ввиде ('Name', 'Course', 'Cost', 'level')

Comment: В таблице несколько строк, вы привели пример одной строки. Добавьте в вопрос понятный пример того, что требуется.

Comment: А все, понял. Написал бы сразу словами, что там столбцы по-разному расположены, чтоб другим людям гадать не пришлось.